# Extremal set with just one point. Then this point is an extreme point.

Tags: functional-analysis

Question: A set $F$ is a single-point set and an extremal set. Therefore, the one
element of $F$ is an extreme point.

Let $X$ be a vector space and suppose $K$ is a convex subset of $X$.
A point $x ∈ K$ is an extreme point of $K$ if it does not lie on a line segment in $K$.
That is, $x$ is an extreme point of $K$ provided that the following is true: If $u$ and $v$ are
elements of $K$ such that $x = (1 − t)u + tv$ for some $t ∈ (0, 1)$, then $x = u = v$.

Let $E$ be a topological vector space with nonempty subset $K$. A
subset $F$ of $K$ is called extremal (in $K$) if $F$ is a nonempty compact convex set such
that the following holds: If $\{u, v\} ⊆ K$ and $(1 − t)u + tv ∈ F$ for all $t ∈ (0, 1)$, then
$\{u, v\} ⊆ F$.

How can this be? I can't understand.
From Bowers and Kalton page 115.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it´s because the definition is wrong. In the definition of extremal, it´s just for some $t \in (0,1)$, not for all.